# Unable to add classy-prelude dependency

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am trying to add `classy-prelude` dependency to my stack project as follows:

```
name:                FooService
version:             0.1.0.0
github:              "githubuser/FooService"
license:             BSD3
author:              "Author name here"
maintainer:          "example@example.com"
copyright:           "2019 Author name here"

extra-source-files:
- README.md
- ChangeLog.md

# Metadata used when publishing your package
# synopsis:            Short description of your package
# category:            Web

# To avoid duplicated efforts in documentation and dealing with the
# complications of embedding Haddock markup inside cabal files, it is
# common to point users to the README.md file.
description:         Please see the README on GitHub at <https://github.com/githubuser/FooService#readme>

dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- classy-prelude

default-extesion:
- NoImplicitPrelude
- OverloadedStrings

library:
  source-dirs: src

executables:
  FooService-exe:
    main:                Main.hs
    source-dirs:         app
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - FooService

tests:
  FooService-test:
    main:                Spec.hs
    source-dirs:         test
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - FooService
```

when call the interactive environment I've got the error message:

```
Using main module: 1. Package `FooService' component FooService:exe:FooService-exe with main-is file: /home/developer/haskell/FooService/app/Main.hs Cabal file info not found for classy-prelude-1.5.0@sha256:ed1a607f688745bc263be0b2ed2492729a62fd4c9821b68c2bfacbd7a9d9293d,1928, updating Selected mirror https://s3.amazonaws.com/hackage.fpcomplete.com/ Downloading timestamp No package index update available, but didn't update cache last time, running now Calculating hashes to check for hackage-security rebases or filesystem changes Updating preexisting cache, should be quick Populating cache from file size 640326144, hash bb56d41c70c9e6cdd625a6c3c7de5f56823e92cc6fe880f8056259ab31d3e0d5 Populating package index cache ... Failed populating package index cache

Error: BadChecksum 0

Warning: Build failed, but trying to launch GHCi anyway The following GHC options are incompatible with GHCi and have not been passed to it:
-threaded Configuring GHCi with the following packages: FooService GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help <command line>: cannot satisfy -package classy-prelude-1.5.0
```

What is missing?

Comment: Which `resolver` are you using?

Comment: The `resolver` is `resolver: lts-14.17`.